# Unable to find Eigen3 with CMake

Tags: c++, cmake, eigen3

I am kind of desperate: 
For my studies I need to work with Eigen and CMake. I'm able to use Eigen if I copy the whole library in the directories where my compiler looks by default but as soon as I try to find it via 
 
`find_package(Eigen3 REQUIRED)`
I get the following error:

```
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:148 (message):
  Could NOT find Eigen3 (missing: EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIR EIGEN3_VERSION_OK)
  (Required is at least version "2.91.0")
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:388 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  FindEigen3.cmake:76 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  CMakeLists.txt:8 (find_package)
```

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!

Now I searched for solutions but all I those I tried (also those available on stackoverflow: 
[Find package Eigen3 for CMake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12249140/find-package-eigen3-for-cmake) 
or 
[CMake Can't find Eigen3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5922016/cmake-cant-find-eigen3) )
did not work.
My Eigen Version (according to the Macros in `Core/util/Macros.h`) is 3.2.5.
I keep the Eigen directory in `/usr/local/include`, I use the `FindEigen3.cmake` which comes with the Eigen library and my `CMakeLists.txt` looks as follows:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project(Test)

set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
find_package(Eigen3 REQUIRED)
include_directories(${EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIR})
message("Found Eigen3 in: ${EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIR}")

add_executable(main test.cpp)
```

Has anyone an idea what's going wrong?

Kind regards,
Julien

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. The find package scripts normally use the [`find_path()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.4/command/find_path.html) command to detect the package's include directory. If it's not found automatically you can extend [`CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.4/variable/CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH.html) by the path where CMake should search (for example see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3808775/cmake-doesnt-find-boost)). So you could add something like `list(APPEND CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH "/usr/local/include")` before your `find_package()` command.

Comment: Thanks! If I add the exact path to the `CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH` it finds the package - but isn't searching manually exactly what I want to avoid? Shouldn't the `find_package()` do that for me?

Comment: You are right. The `CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH` was meant for a non-standard `Eigen` installation path. I have given your code sample a try and - if I install `Eigen` into the default path - it seems to work without the need to give the path (see my answer). If you have already used the `Eigen` installation process, could you please add more details on your environment (CMake version, CMake command line call, host OS, compiler version, ...)?

Comment: Curious, is this about caffe and AI?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

*Turning my comment into an answer*

The find package scripts - like `FindEigen3.cmake` - normally use the `find_path()` command to detect the package's include directory (see [it's documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.4/command/find_path.html) for the full details).

`FindEigen3.cmake` uses the following code snippet:

> ```
> find_path(EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIR NAMES signature_of_eigen3_matrix_library
>     PATHS
>     ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/include
>     ${KDE4_INCLUDE_DIR}
>     PATH_SUFFIXES eigen3 eigen
> )
> ```

So it looks in [`CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.4/variable/CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX.html) which on Unix/Linux hosts is `/usr/local` by default.

The following has worked for me:

- Go to the `Eigen` source directory and run the CMake and installation steps

  ```
  > mkdir build
  > cd build
  > cmake ..
  > make install
  ```
- Then copy - as you have done - `FindEigen3.cmake` to your projects source directory.
- Now your code does find `Eigen` (just changed to `list(APPEND ...)`)

  ```
  list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}")
  find_package(Eigen3 REQUIRED)
  ```

**References**

- [Eigen & CMake](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=CMake)
- [CMake: Of what use is find_package() if you need to specify CMAKE_MODULE_PATH anyway?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20746936/cmake-of-what-use-is-find-package-if-you-need-to-specify-cmake-module-path-an)
- [Cmake doesn't find Boost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3808775/cmake-doesnt-find-boost)

Comment: Perfect it's working now! I think what also caused problems is, that I didnt use `$ make install` to install the Library but just copied it in my `/usr/local/include`. The directory `FindEigen3.cmake` was looking for was probably too deep (it was somewhere in `/usr/include/Eigen_all/eigen-tar-folder-name/`). Anyways - thank you very much for your detailed answer!

Answer (score 1):

Add the path of `FindEigen3.cmake` before `find_package(Eigen3 REQUIRED)`, like this:

```
LIST(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "/usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/")
find_package(Eigen3)
```

Comment: There is no needs to add `Modules/` directory, **shipped with CMake**, into `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH`: CMake searches in this directory in any case.