# CMake Error with Eigen 3.3.4

Tags: cmake, opensuse, eigen3

I am trying to compile dolfin on openSUSE Leap 42.3. I get an error with CMake when it tries to find Eigen3. I have Eigen3.3.4 installed on my machine and the error is

```
CMake Error at cmake/modules/FindEigen3.cmake:42 (file):
   file failed to open for reading (No such file or directory):

      /usr//usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/util/Macros.h
```

I don't know why the extra `/usr/` is popping up at the beginning. Can anyone help me? I can't find a solution online.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this was an...interesting, but perhaps silly error. Forgive me...I'm new to openSUSE. I originally installed eigen3 through YaST. This did not come with a CMakeList.txt file, so naturally I was confused by the answer in [c++ - Unable to find Eigen3 with CMake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34138879/unable-to-find-eigen3-with-cmake). Moreover I was confused because Eigen is just header files, so naturally I assumed there would be nothing to make.

Long story short, there are MakeList's for Eigen. You just have to download the tarball from eigen.tuxfamily.org, then build them with cmake.

Answer (score 0):

dolfin? I want to know are you in the CFD area. 
  I also have Eigen installed in my leap 42.3. But i installed it from the official website of Eigen. I think you may have a try and then specify the folder of the Eigne in Cmake-gui.
  Good luck to you.