# How to enable pkg-config support in eigen3 on Windows?

Tags: cmake, eigen3, pkg-config

I am compiling a 3rd party library which uses the following commands to find Eigen3:

```
find_package( PkgConfig )
pkg_check_modules( EIGEN3 REQUIRED eigen3 )
include_directories(${EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIRS})
```

The `find_package( PkgConfig )` command runs correctly because I specified the `PKG_CONFIG_EXECUTABLE` variable. But `pkg_check_modules( EIGEN3 REQUIRED eigen3 )` returns an error:

> -- Checking for module 'eigen3'
>
> --   No package 'eigen3' found

The Eigen3's [official webpage](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/GettingStarted.html) says "It is not necessary to use CMake or install anything." It took me quite a while to realize this statement is wrong. So I ran the following to compile and install Eigen3 (version 3.3.5):

```
cmake -DCMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES=Release -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=E:\3rd-parties\eigen-3.3.5\install_ -G"Visual Studio 14 2015 Win64" ..
```

The compilation and installation process were both successful because I didn't see any failure in VS2015. But, when I go back to the build folder of the 3rd party library and run cmake again, I got exactly the same error. Eigen3 [official website](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicCMakeGuide.html) only provides an instruction using `find_package`, but not pkg-config.exe, so I next searched Google and find this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5922016/cmake-cant-find-eigen3). The answer says we need to "enable pkg-config support in the eigen3 cmake". I don't know how to enable it. Is there any specific CMake variable for this purpose? Since it is a new problem, and [Eigen's main page](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page) says "To get help, stackoverflow is your best resource." so I come here for help. My question is: how to enable pkg-config support in eigen3? Or to put it another way: how to pass the `pkg_check_modules( EIGEN3 REQUIRED eigen3 )` cmake command? Thanks a lot.

PS: I am working on Windows 10.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the Eigen3 [sources](https://bitbucket.org/eigen/eigen/src/d244e1fa21d2cf1f2785047047f6d8b6ce831bb2/CMakeLists.txt?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#CMakeLists.txt-135), an option `EIGEN_BUILD_PKGCONFIG` is responsible on `pkg-config` support.

On Windows the whole option is disabled, but you may try to set it:

```
cmake -DEIGEN_BUILD_PKGCONFIG=ON <... other arguments>
```

When use `pkg-config` for find Eigen3 in CMake script, make sure that installation directory of Eigen3 is listed in `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` variable. (If CMake version used by a project is less than 3.1, then you need to additionally set `PKG_CONFIG_USE_CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` to `ON` for tell `pkgconfig` module to use variable `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH`. See more in the [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindPkgConfig.html) for `pkgconfig` module.)

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I added the `EIGEN_BUILD_PKGCONFIG` option when building Eigen3 and it works on Windows. A new folder `E:\3rd-parties\eigen-3.3.5\install_\share\pkgconfig` is created and a file `eigen3.pc` is in it. But `pkg-config.exe` is still unable to find Eigen3 after I tried various values for `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH`. Could you please give me one more help about how to instruct `pkg-config` to locate where Eigen3 installation is? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hm, passing option `-DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=E:/3rd-parties/eigen-3.3.5/install_` to `cmake` (or corresponding setting in CMake GUI) should work.

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't work. The document of CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH says it supports find_package(), find_program(), find_library(), find_file(), and find_path(). Does it mean CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH only work with these functions, but not with pkg_check_modules()?

Comment: I was gussing right, pkg_check_modules uses FindPkgConfig(), while CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH works only with find_package(), find_program(), find_library(), find_file(), and find_path(). There is a variable in FindPkgConfig() that controls whether it uses CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH -- PKG_CONFIG_USE_CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH. It is enabled by default if the minimum CMake version is >= 3.1, but the 3rd-party library I am compiling happens to set it to 2.8 ..... I have edited your answer to include this trick.

Comment: I have rephrased you edit to a simpler form, which notes about specific of low version of CMake.